# How to level unequal ceiling fan blades

Tags: ceiling-fan

So my ceiling fan was wobbling. I realized 2 blades (out of 5) were warped. I bought 5 new blades and made sure they were equal in weight and weren't warped. My fan still wobble a little bit and when I measured from the ceiling to blades, one blade was about 1/2-1 inch lower than the other blades. How can I level the blades?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What make and model of fan do you have?

Comment: Are the [blade arms/brackets](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&q=fan+blade+arm) all properly secured to the motor assembly? Are the blades all properly secured to their arms? Tighten all of those connections first. If the answer to both of those questions is already a yes, and you've already confirmed that the new blades are all flat/even, maybe one of the arms itself is bent?

Comment: The height isn't the issue, it's the balance.  It is not enough for all the blades to weigh the same... balance *within* each blade is the issue. After all, this is a radial machine.

Comment: There's more to fixing fan wobble than blade balance. I recently fixed one in my new home by tightening the ball socket at the junction box and the downrod screws at the motor. There was so much slop in the system that no amount of balancing would've done the job.

Comment: There is still a lot we don't know.  How much wobble are we talking about? What particular speed is the fan running when it starts to wobble. Is this a ceiling hugger or does it drop down from the ceiling? If it does drop down how much? What is the age of the fan? Does it hang from a flat ceiling or is it slanted. If you can answer all or any of these questions. It would help us give you a better answer.

Comment: A photo would help a lot.  But it depends on how they are attached.  If by bolts, then perhaps washers or even shims might help.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One of the screws that held the down rod was loose. Tightening it fix the problem.